# Can I save results anyway even when Keyboardinterrupt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboardinterrupt

I have a very long code which is taking forever to run. I was wondering if there is a way to save the results even if I use the keyboard to interrupt the code from running? All the examples I found were using except with Keyboardinterrupt, so I don't know if this is the right code to use.

More concretely: I have a code which ends with saving results in a list, and returning the list. In this case, is there a way to return the list despite keyboardinterrupt? Can I use `if keyboardinterrupt` statement?

My code:

```
# removed is a very long list

for a, b in itertools.combinations(removed, 2):
        temp = [a,b]
        Token_Set_Ratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(temp[0],temp[1])
        if Token_Set_Ratio > k:
            c = random.choice(temp)
            if c in removed:
                removed.remove(c)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    return removed
```

Where can I add the part for python to retain removed even if keyboard interrupt occurs?

Comment: Do you still want the program to terminate after? Or continue with the partial results?

Comment: @iz_ continue with the partial results. I added the last part of the code to the post.

Comment: It probably is operating system specific. Not the same on Linux and Windows. Please edit your question to explain which OS are you using. i downvoted your question because you did not explain that. For Linux read [ALP](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Comment: And there are more *efficient* data structures than just plain lists. Read for example [*Introduction to Algorithms*](http://web.karabuk.edu.tr/hakankutucu/CME222/MIT[1].Press.Introduction.to.Algorithms.2nd.Edition.eBook-TLFeBOOK.pdf). So if I could, I would downvote your question twice (once for no mention of OS, another time for lack of research). So I also voted to close your unclear question.

Comment: At last, you can code in Python on computers without screens (think of a web server using [HTTPserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)) and without keyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `try`-`except` with `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
def your_function():
    removed = [...]

    try:
        # Code that takes long time
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(removed, 2):
            ...
        return removed
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return removed
```

A small example:

```
import time

def foo():
    result = []
    try:
        # Long running code
        for i in range(10000):
            result.append(i)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        return result
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Code to "save"
        return result

print(foo())
```

When you Ctrl-C before the end of execution, a partial list is printed.